# Can a node module consisting of Facebook React code work within ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, react-native, npm, office-fabric

ASP.NET has a [nuget package called ReactJS.net](https://reactjs.net) which is capable of running Facebook React v16+ code.

I'd like to integrate [Office UI Fabric](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric), but the react package is only available as an NPM package, where I'd run

```
npm install office-ui-fabric-react --save
```

Is it possible to take the contents of this code and integrate it into ASP.NET (MVC/Core)?

- Should I "do something" with the github source and add it to my code? (e.g. rename the necessary files to jsx)
- Should I create a temporary node project, install the package, and manually copy data over?
- Is there another way I'm not listing (a utility, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the ASP.NET ReactJS.net Plugin, but from what I can gather it requires you to generate a bundle that contains all the dependencies you want to use with it and include in your ASP.net template.

To create a bundle that excludes `react` from the `office-ui-fabric-react` module, I would use webpack to build the bundle and the exclude `react` as a dependency bundled in the bundle.

> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/